# Does Kotlin support monadic comprehension?

Tags: kotlin

Like LINQ in C#, for comprehension in Scala, anything similar in Kotlin? If not supported, is it planned?

Comment: I think, there has been some miscommunication here. There's no such policy as not to use monads anywhere. Some monad-like constructs, such as safe calls for nullable types, are built into the language. We do not support comprehensions at the moment, but this feature is on the table.

Comment: As @AndreyBreslav noted, Kotlin does use monadic constructions where it makes sense. What I said in my answer is that there is no goal to use monads in **every** single language concept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no special keyword (do/for) and so no direct translation to nested flatMap (desugaring) like in other languages.

But monadic comprehension can be implemented with coroutines.

From Arrow documentation : https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/monad_comprehensions/#comprehensions-over-coroutines

> Comprehensions over coroutines
>
> This feature is known with multiple names: async/await, coroutines, do
>   notation, for comprehensions…each version contains certain unique
>   points but all derive from the same principles. In Kotlin, coroutines
>   (introduced in version 1.1 of the language) make the compiler capable
>   of rewriting seemingly synchronous code into asynchronous sequences.
>   Arrow uses this capability of the compiler to bring you
>   coroutines-like notation to all instances of the Monad typeclass.
>
> This means that comprehensions are available for Option, Try, List,
>   Reader, Observable, Flux or IO all the same.

For coroutines, see also "Deep dive into Coroutines on JVM @ KotlinConf 2017" :  https://www.slideshare.net/elizarov/deep-dive-into-coroutines-on-jvm-kotlinconf-2017?next_slideshow=1

Answer (score 6):

In the preview version of Kotlin 1.1 there's universal `async`/`await` syntax which can be used for different kinds of monadic comprehensions:

> Many languages (starting with C# in 2012) support asynchronous
>   programming through dedicated language constructs such as async/await
>   keywords. In Kotlin, we generalized this concept so that libraries can
>   define their own versions of such constructs, and async is not a
>   keyword, but simply a function.
>
> This design allows for integration of different asynchronous APIs:
>   futures/promises, callback-passing, etc. It is also general enough to
>   express lazy generators (yield) and cover some other use cases.

<sup>[source](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/07/first-glimpse-of-kotlin-1-1-coroutines-type-aliases-and-more/)</sup>