# Leverage suspending functions for implementing a CPS-style interpreter

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, f#, kotlin-coroutines

I recently came across [this](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-turtle-2/) superb blog post, where the author demonstrates several functional design patterns by giving 13 examples to implement turtle graphics. The code is in F# and I was wondering how well it would translate to Kotlin. I am particularly interested in way #13, the interpreter pattern.

The types translate very well to Kotlin.

```kotlin
sealed class PenColor {
    object Black : PenColor()
    object Yellow : PenColor()
}

sealed class MoveResponse {
    object MoveOk : MoveResponse()
    object HitABarrier : MoveResponse()
}

sealed class SetColorResponse {
    object ColorOk : SetColorResponse()
    object OutOfInk : SetColorResponse()
}

sealed class TurtleProgram<T> {
    data class Stop<T>(val value: T) : TurtleProgram<T>()
    data class Move<T>(val distance: Double, val cont: (MoveResponse) -> TurtleProgram<T>) : TurtleProgram<T>()
    data class Turn<T>(val angle: Double, val cont: () -> TurtleProgram<T>) : TurtleProgram<T>()
    data class PenUp<T>(val cont: () -> TurtleProgram<T>) : TurtleProgram<T>()
    data class PenDown<T>(val cont: () -> TurtleProgram<T>) : TurtleProgram<T>()
    data class SetColor<T>(val color: PenColor, val cont: (SetColorResponse) -> TurtleProgram<T>) : TurtleProgram<T>()
}
```

Next an example is given, which shows how to represent a program that draws a triangle. In Kotlin this would be:

```
val program =
    Move(100.0) {
        Turn(120.0) {
            Move(100.0) {
                Turn(120.0) {
                    Move(100.0) {
                        Turn(120.0) {
                            Stop(Unit)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course this is very ugly. The author goes on by creating something called a "computation expression". This is the F#'s answer to the do-notation and allows to flatten nested programs so that they look imperative.

I was wondering if there is an idiomatic way to achieve a flat representation in Kotlin as well?   Especially the `cont`-values in the `TurtleProgram` classes look like they could be replaced by suspending functions, since as far as I understand a suspending function already returns a continuation. However, my limited understanding of the mechanisms under the hood block me from going on from there.

Comment: A computation expression is a fancier form of monad comprehensions. I don't know Kotlin, but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885266/1346276) helps?

Comment: This is Arrow's monad comprehension. I looked into it and they somehow use suspending functions, but they implement it only for their own monads and I'd like to use it for my own monad. Copying the trick is beyond the scope of my abilities, hence the question.


I know that the continuation monad (with syntactic sugar) is baked in into Kotlin and thought I could use it to solve my problem.